# Spring Multiple Implementation of same interface

Tags: java, spring

I have an Interface and multiple implementation classes, around 10, of this interface.

I have a naming convention like `prefix + name + suffix` so during runtime, I can add

`@Autowired
private Map<String, MyInterface> myImplementations;`

 and then access the implementation class with `myImplementations.get()` method.

Is there a better way of accessing those implementations? I only know which impl. I needed during runtime, changes depends on the message I received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [BeanFactoryAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryAware.html) interface in your class and then use injected bean factory to get needed implementation:

```
Interface impl = beanFactory.getBean("interfaceimpl");
```

or

```
Interface impl = beanFactory.getBean(InterfaceImpl.class);
```

Comment: Is is somehow better than my current approach ? Because I need to implement another interface in your case ?

Comment: It is more in the "Spring way" of doing things. Moreover, if it happens that you add new implementations and reload context at runtime, you won't need to reconfigure anything, because Spring will do it for you.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. I just need to implement BeanFactoryAware once, on the class that I'm doing the job, or a separate one, not all implementations. That's very nice, thanks.